# PHP/MySQL - Checkboxes into Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I found a few topics here on StackOverflow and I read a bit about how to insert data from checkboxes into a MySQL database. I read about using an array to insert the values into the database. Problem is now, that all data from my form are included as soon as I press the submit button except the checkbox values. So the form works as it should, only the checkbox values are not inserted into my database. Here is what I did:

A part of my form:

```
<form method="post" action="add_schulen.php" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Name Schule:  </label>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="schulname" class="form-control" placeholder="Namen der Schule">
</div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 profile_left">
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1A"> 1A <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1B"> 1B <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1C"> 1C <br /> 
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1D"> 1D <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1E"> 1E <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1F"> 1F <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1G"> 1G <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1H"> 1H <br />
    </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 profile_left">

         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2A"> 2A <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2B"> 2B <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2C"> 2C <br /> 
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2D"> 2D <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2E"> 2E <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2F"> 2F <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2G"> 2G <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2H"> 2H <br />
</div>
    <button type="submit" name="addschulen" value="addschulen" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg pull-right">Schule anlegen</button>
</form>
```

My complete PHP code at the top of my add_schulen.php:

```
<?php 
include 'inc/database.php';    

// Check if form is submitted
if (isset ($_POST['addschulen'])) {
    $schulname = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['schulname']);
    $ansprechperson = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['ansprechperson']);
    $schulstrasse = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['schulstrasse']);
    $schulplz = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['schulplz']);
    $schulort = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['schulort']);
    $schultelefon = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['schultelefon']);
    $klassen = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['schulen']);

        // Setting up a blank variable to be used in the coming loop.
      $alleKlassen = "";

      // For every checkbox value sent to the form.
      foreach ($klassen as $klasse) {
        // Append the string with the current array element, and then add a comma and a space at the end.
        $alleKlassen .= $klasse . ", ";
      }

      $query_insert_schule = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `schule` (`schulname`, `ansprechperson`, `schulstrasse`, `schulplz`, `schulort`, `schultelefon`, `klasse`)
            VALUES ('$schulname', '$ansprechperson', '$schulstrasse', '$schulplz', '$schulort', '$schultelefon', '$alleKlassen')"); 

if (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 0) //<--
{
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    $msg_success= '<strong>Gratulation!</strong> Die Schule wurde erfolgreich hinzugefügt. Zur <a href="schulverwaltung.php"><span style="color:#fff;">Übersicht aller Schulen >></span></a>';
}       

}        
?>
```

As I said all data are included as soon as I click on the submit button, except the checkbox values. Does anyone have an idea why? What I am doing wrong? This is the first time I try to insert checkbox values into my database.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: try `$klassen = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['schulen[]']);`

Comment: Thank you for your help but still the same issue. Everything goes into my database except the checkbox values

Comment: What does `var_dump($klassen);` give (before any modifications)?

Comment: I entered var_dump($klassen); after my foreach function. It looks like this: 'foreach ($klassen as $klasse) { $alleKlassen .= $klasse . ", "; } var_dump($klassen);' and it shows me nothing as soon as I click on the submit button. Did I insereted the var_dump wrong?

Comment: @ChristophC. I think you misunderstood me. If you do `var_dump($klassen);` directly after the `$_POST`s are being fetched, then run the form, what values does `var_dump($klassen);` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i have tryied and it worked for just didnt insert into db but i just printed it out. try taking away the string escape from `$_POST['schulen']` since that is already cleaned/ prefdefined data. and also use `substr()` to remove the last comma at the end of the array.

try this:

```
<?php
// Check if form is submitted
if (isset ($_POST['addschulen'])) {
    $schulname =  $_POST['schulname'];
    $ansprechperson =$_POST['ansprechperson'];
    $schulstrasse = $_POST['schulstrasse'];
    $schulplz =$_POST['schulplz'];
    $schulort = $_POST['schulort'];
    $schultelefon =$_POST['schultelefon'];
    $klassen = $_POST['schulen'];

        // Setting up a blank variable to be used in the coming loop.
      $alleKlassen = "";

      // For every checkbox value sent to the form.
      foreach ($klassen as $klasse) {
        // Append the string with the current array element, and then add a comma and a space at the end.
        $alleKlassen .= $klasse . ", ";
      }
    $alleKlassen  = substr($alleKlassen , 0, -2);
    print_r($alleKlassen);

}else{
    echo '<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Name Schule:  </label>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="schulname" class="form-control" placeholder="Namen der Schule">
</div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 profile_left">
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1A"> 1A <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1B"> 1B <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1C"> 1C <br /> 
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1D"> 1D <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1E"> 1E <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1F"> 1F <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1G"> 1G <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="1H"> 1H <br />
    </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 profile_left">

         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2A"> 2A <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2B"> 2B <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2C"> 2C <br /> 
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2D"> 2D <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2E"> 2E <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2F"> 2F <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2G"> 2G <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="schulen[]" value="2H"> 2H <br />
</div>
    <button type="submit" name="addschulen" value="addschulen" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg pull-right">Schule anlegen</button>
</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: AWESOME thank you so much! That´s it! It was because of the string escape! I did not know that :)! And one last thing: Can you also tell me what my code should look like, when I now want to output those checkboxes from the database into a dropdown list? So that on another page a user can select from a dropdown list every checkbox that I have included into my database?

Comment: ohkk i hope this helps, when u have a string in php like this  `$checkbox= "1A,2C,7N";` you can use the ['explode()'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to get them individually so you can put it in the dropdown .    try this   or  check it out [here](http://codepad.org/t0z1W3Vg )

Comment: thank you! I looked at the codepad link and I will try it out. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using html arrays you must foreach on them like an array:

```
$schulen= $_POST['schulen'];
foreach( $schulen as $s ){
    //code
}
```

now if you write: echo $s; (under //code) it will print the value of the checkbox that were checked by the user... so now it should be easy for you to solve ;)
example, if you want to escape:

```
$schulen= $_POST['schulen'];
for( $i=0; $i< count($schulen); $i++ ){
    $schulen[ $i ]= mysqli_real_escape_string( $schulen[ $i ] );
}
```

if you want to put into database you need an apropriate filed (example: a text field will be good)
then you must use implode & explode...
to put the array: $todatabase= implode( $schulen, '|' );
to get the array: $schulen= explode( '|', $fromdatabase );

Comment: I wrote now: foreach ($klassen as $klasse) { echo $klasse; } and as soon as I submit my form, it is the same...everything is inserted into my database except the checkbox values

Comment: He doesn't have to use `implode` or `explode`, he's building a string from the array in the `foreach`.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) and look what you get from checkboxes! Try to add some of them manually to mysql!

Comment: `$alleKlassen = "";
  foreach ($schulen as $klasse) {
        $alleKlassen .= $klasse . ", ";
  }`

after my second example then should be fine!